# Table of Contents - add a dot between number and title

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm fairly new to Latex. I tried to make the table of contents like:

> CHAPTER
>
> I.TEXT
>
> A. Text
>
> B. Text

In main body, I use

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\ }
\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
```

to create headings like:

> A. Text
>
> paragraphs
>
> 1.Text
>
> paragraphs

And it works well.

But when I use

```
\tableofcontents
```

to create the contents, it shows me:

> CHAPTER
>
> I. TEXT
>
> A Text
>
> B Text

So only the chapter title has a dot after its number, subsection and subsubsection don't. And there are many spaces between the number and title.
How can I add the dot back and reduce the unwanted spaces?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Are you trying to produce appendices? Please say more about what you want to do with a MWE.